# How to code Retractable fixed sidebar with example

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do code something like this? 
http://tinyurl.com/retractablesidebar

Its a retractable fixed sidebar. 
From Googling, i have found similar sidebar (http://www.berriart.com/sidr/)
However, it closes completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wondering how to code the sidebar only you can can do it mainly with CSS and a little javascript function. I have assemble

**[a demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZvV6HqyKo2zF2A0mulgK?p=preview)**

where you will have all the needed CSS to achieve what you want. BUt the most important rules are those ones :

```
.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.sidebar.maximized {
  width: 190px;
}
.body {
  margin-left: 190px;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.body.minimized {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

The javascript function only add and remove CSS classes and can be done like that :

```
var onClick = function () {
  var sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
  var body = document.querySelector('.body');
  var classNames = document.querySelector('.sidebar').className;
  if(classNames.indexOf('maximized') > -1) {
    sidebar.className = 'sidebar';
    body.className = 'body minimized';
  } else {
    sidebar.className = 'sidebar maximized';
    body.className = 'body';
  }
  return false;
};
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you! that is what i am looking for. once again, thank you :D